# Alignment of long tick mark labels after rotation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem of my y tick mark labels not aligning after rotation in my `matplotlib` figure. It only seems to occur with long labels, I have played with the alignment, but that only pushes the text into the figure. Not really sure what to do from here.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
bmNames = np.array(['XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
       'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
       'XXXXXXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXX',
       'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXX'], 
      dtype='|S25')
nCols = bmNames.shape[0]
data = np.random.random((nCols, nCols))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
tick_marks = np.arange(nCols)

ax.set_yticks(tick_marks)
lbs = ax.set_yticklabels(bmNames, rotation=45, ha='right')

ax.set_xticks(tick_marks)
lbs = ax.set_xticklabels(tick_marks+1, rotation=45)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `rotation_mode='anchor'`to your `yticklabels` should solve your problem:

```
lbs = ax.set_yticklabels(bmNames, rotation=45, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor')
```

It does what the name suggests: it rotates on the label's anchor (right) instead of the strings center.
Found it in the [Documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=set_yticklabels#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels)